# 'zinnia_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, zinnia

I am trying to override the zinnia templates in my django project. I have placed the file `base.html` at `\templates\zinnia\` with the following contents:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load zinnia_tags i18n  %}

{% block sidebar %}
Change.
{% endblock %}
```

But when I visit `\weblog`, I get the error :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /weblog/
'zinnia_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library zinnia_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.zinnia_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.zinnia_tags,django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.zinnia_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.zinnia_tags,endless_pagination.templatetags.zinnia_tags,haystack.templatetags.zinnia_tags,notifications.templatetags.zinnia_tags,links.templatetags.zinnia_tags,allauth.account.templatetags.zinnia_tags,allauth.socialaccount.templatetags.zinnia_tags,django_comments.templatetags.zinnia_tags,mptt.templatetags.zinnia_tags,tagging.templatetags.zinnia_tags,zinnia.templatetags.zinnia_tags
```

I have tried this based on the idea mentioned in their [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-blog-zinnia/hQRv01egorw/BAdRuq-YAN0J)

I have loaded the zinnia template dir in my settings.py. I am unable to figure out why I get the error.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Did you set up your `INSTALLED_APPS` as documented? See http://django-blog-zinnia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/install.html#applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/f7b32fe49ecc365b13f20e8557b3a1cb6fb0df20/CHANGELOG#L25, you need to import `zinnia`, and not `zinnia_tags`.

Comment: just one more question, is `django-contrib-comments` a mandatory dependency for zinnia? as after installing zinnia, I get a an error - `Cannot resolve keyword 'flags' into field` and from this link - https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/issues/172 , it says that we need to install django-contrib-comments to get rid of it..

Comment: `contrib.comments` is a part of django, you can include it in django settings by adding it to installed apps. But this module is deprecated in django 1.8, we will see how author of zinnia will deal with it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but I am talking about django-contrib-comments - https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments as without installing it, I am getting the error. But if i install it, I will have to port my existing data to  it..

Comment: Zinnia is using `contrib.comments`, so you HAVE to install it (https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/develop/setup.py#L36). Due to django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/comments/ it is recommended to install it from external repo, as you have done it.